# how to execute a php script?

Tags: php

how do you execute a php script on a site thats not mine?i need to know this because, i found in a site where you have to multiply 2 large numbers and find its product within 1 sec....a normal man can't do this even with the help of a calculator, because what they meant was to program and find out the result...i know how to write that script but don't know where to put that script in that site and execute....any suggestions gladly accepted...

Comment: You can't put a PHP script on someone's server unless you have access. We need more info for a better answer

Comment: Write a program on your own system and just submit the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check out the source of the page, and write a javascript to pull the numbers from the page and submit the answer.

You can use a Firefox addon such as Greasemonkey to run the script on the page.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Answer (score 2):

you can use php curl remote server access. but you must have the permission

Answer (score 0):

If the site you need to submit the answer to uses a form, it might be possible to write your own form and post it to that site.  Most sites block that kind of behavior though.